# Where to set path for servlet libraries in Tomcat?

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, java, libraries

I am trying to follow some good-practice methods and not place the servlet jars into the java install.

Instead what I am hoping to do is figure out the correct way to point to the servlet jars.

If my tomcat jars are in /urs/local/tomcat/lib - how should I configure it so my Ubuntu actually understands to look for those libraries there when I try to compile stuff? :)

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

into catalina.sh you can set the CLASSPATH 
a different option is to set it into your .profile | .bash_profile | .bashrc

```
sh syntax
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/urs/local/tomcat/lib
```

to compile use the sh option and then issue javac .... here is not ubuntu who needs to understand but rather the java compiler (javac)

Comment: is syntax some script that I need to edit?  Where is it usually located?

Comment: in linux open a command line terminal